# Spark job-server scala.MatchError while submitting WordCountExample

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

When I submit a job to the Spark job-server, I can see that the Spark context is created. However, there is an error in `WebApi.getJobManagerForContext` method:

> [2018-06-11 07:05:24,495] INFO  ocalContextSupervisorActor [] [] -
>   SparkContext 9f3d1f60-spark.jobserver.WordCountExample initialized {
>   "status": "ERROR",   "result": {
>       "message": "(Actor[akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/9f3d1f60-spark.jobserver.WordCountExample#-1687191062],Actor[akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/global-result-actor#1953406985])
>   (of class scala.Tuple2)",
>       "errorClass": "scala.MatchError",
>       "stack": "scala.MatchError: (Actor[akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/9f3d1f60-spark.jobserver.WordCountExample#-1687191062],Actor[akka://JobServer/user/context-supervisor/global-result-actor#1953406985])
>   (of class scala.Tuple2)
>           at spark.jobserver.WebApi.spark$jobserver$WebApi$$getJobManagerForContext(WebApi.scala:728)
>           at spark.jobserver.WebApi$$anonfun$jobRoutes$1$$anonfun$apply$75$$anonfun$apply$76.apply(WebApi.scala:640)
>           at spark.jobserver.WebApi$$anonfun$jobRoutes$1$$anonfun$apply$75$$anonfun$apply$76.apply(WebApi.scala:630)
>           at spray.routing.ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$17$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ApplyConverterInstances.scala:60)
>           at spray.routing.ApplyConverterInstances$$anon$17$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ApplyConverterInstances.scala:59)
>           at spray.routing.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$3$$anon$4$$anonfun$happly$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Directive.scala:38)
>           at spray.routing.ConjunctionMagnet$$anon$3$$anon$4$$anonfun$happly$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Directive.scala:37)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$2.happly(BasicDirectives.scala:79)
>           at spray.routing.Directive$$anon$7$$anonfun$happly$4.apply(Directive.scala:86)
>           at spray.routing.Directive$$anon$7$$anonfun$happly$4.apply(Directive.scala:86)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anonfun$mapRequestContext$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:30)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:32)
>           at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:31)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anonfun$withRejectionHandling$1.applyOrElse(RequestContext.scala:130)
>           at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anon$1.handle(RequestContext.scala:84)
>           at akka.spray.UnregisteredActorRefBase.$bang(UnregisteredActorRefBase.scala:72)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anon$3.handle(RequestContext.scala:102)
>           at akka.spray.UnregisteredActorRefBase.$bang(UnregisteredActorRefBase.scala:72)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext.reject(RequestContext.scala:202)
>           at spray.routing.directives.RouteDirectives$$anon$1.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:35)
>           at spray.routing.directives.RouteDirectives$$anon$1.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:34)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.directives.BasicDirectives$$anon$3$$anonfun$happly$1.apply(BasicDirectives.scala:92)
>           at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:32)
>           at spray.routing.RouteConcatenation$RouteConcatenation$$anonfun$$tilde$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteConcatenation.scala:31)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anonfun$withRejectionHandling$1.applyOrElse(RequestContext.scala:130)
>           at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anon$1.handle(RequestContext.scala:84)
>           at akka.spray.UnregisteredActorRefBase.$bang(UnregisteredActorRefBase.scala:72)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext$$anon$3.handle(RequestContext.scala:102)
>           at akka.spray.UnregisteredActorRefBase.$bang(UnregisteredActorRefBase.scala:72)
>           at spray.routing.RequestContext.reject(RequestContext.scala:202)
>           at spray.routing.directives.RouteDirectives$$anon$1.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:35)
>           at spray.routing.directives.RouteDirectives$$anon$1.apply(RouteDirectives.scala:34)"
>   }

Comment: How does your code look like?

Comment: Haven't written any code. It is the WordCountExample in spark-jobserver. The command I use to submit the job is: curl -d "input.string = a b c a b see" "localhost:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=spark.jobserver.WordCountExample"

Comment: No resolution of this problem?